# Why in HMs Location Awareness enter barrier, status change to FALSE after few seconds while executing the application?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When I am using HMS Location Awareness enter barrier, status change to FALSE after few seconds while executing the app. I am not getting any error on execution. How can solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LocationBarrier three methods are there

1. enter
2. exit
3. stay

The **enter** and **exit** barriers **status will change to FALSE after five seconds**. So if you need status to be  TRUE whenever you are in a particular location you have to use **stay** barrier.

In stay barrier you have to mention minimum stay time in the specified area.

Syntax:

**public static AwarenessBarrier stay(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, long timeOfDuration)**

You can refer the below link to know more about Location Awareness.

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201302980400000072&fid=0101187876626530001&pid=0301303616533430214